# How to specify a file that is a few folders back in Jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2

So I am trying to make a website with Flask. So I made a `base.html` file. But its not on the same folder as the main `index.html`! So when i do:

```
{% extends "../../templates/base.html" %}
```

It says ../../templates/base.html template not found!

The directory tree is:

```
src/
├─ home/
│  ├─ static/
│  ├─ templates/
│     ├─ index.html
├─ static/
├─ templates/
   ├─ base.html
```

**So how can I link `index.html` to extend `base.html`?**

Comment: please provide more context  as to where your are running from. If I had to guess, you should use "templates/base.html" and it should work (but again its a guess based on what you have here)

Comment: I do {% extends "../../templates/base.html" %} from src/home/index.html but the base is in src/templates/base.html

Comment: the python file is in src/home/routes.py

Comment: Where your python code located at?